# Python character count

Tags: python

I have been going over python tutorials in this [resource](http://openbookproject.net/thinkcs/python/english2e/ch10.htmloutfile.close()). Everything is pretty clear in the below code which counts number of characters. Only section that i dont understand is the section where count assigned to a list and multiplied by 120. Can anyone explain what is the purpose of this in plain english please.

```
def display(i):
    if i == 10: return 'LF'
    if i == 13: return 'CR'
    if i == 32: return 'SPACE'
    return chr(i)

infile = open('alice_in_wonderland.txt', 'r')
text = infile.read()
infile.close()

counts = 128 * [0]

for letter in text:
    counts[ord(letter)] += 1

outfile = open('alice_counts.dat', 'w')
outfile.write("%-12s%s\n" % ("Character", "Count"))
outfile.write("=================\n")

for i in range(len(counts)):
    if counts[i]:
        outfile.write("%-12s%d\n" % (display(i), counts[i]))

outfile.close()
```

Comment: Unrelated to your question: Note: This code assumes that the the alice_in_wonderland.txt file only contains ASCII characters. That may be fine for an example, but is a dangerous assumption for real-word files.

Comment: Your code looks like it would run OK with Python 1.5. Perhaps you should look for a more up-to-date tutorial -- one that mentions `defaultdict` would be a good idea :-)

Comment: @user74283, remember you can always obtain really fast answers to these and similar questions by inserting 'print counts' into your code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`128 * [0]` creates a list of 128 elements, each with a value of 0.

```
>>> 3 * [0]
[0, 0, 0]
```

Then, since valid ASCII characters are in the range 0-127, each letter accesses an index in counts (`ord(letter)` will return the numeric value of a character), and increments the value at that index.

For example, the character `'0'` corresponds to a numeric value of 48.  So when a `'0'` is encountered, `counts[48]` is incremented by 1.

Answer (score 3):

As the other answers explain, it creates a 128-list of `0`. What they don't explain is that it's the *same* `0`, *128 times*. Since `int` is immutable this masks a problem that many novice Python programmers run into:

```
>>> l = [[]] * 5
>>> l
[[], [], [], [], []]
>>> l[0].append(1)
>>> l
[[1], [1], [1], [1], [1]]
```

Comment: Yes, that's dangerous but only for complex data types. It's OK in Mark's example since there are only ints in the list.

Comment: Of course, if all one does is *assign* objects to the list indices, (im)mutability of the list contents is totally irrelevant: `l= 4*[[]]; print l; l[0]= "hi"; print l`.

Answer (score 1):

The line `counts = 128 * [0]` populates a 128-element list with zeroes.

This list is then use to increment character counts based on each character's ascii value, since ascii values range from 0 to 127.